# Checking $( \binom{n}{k} - \binom{n-k}{k}) / \binom{n}{k} < \frac{k^2}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$ and $k$ be integers with $2\leq k \leq n$. I want to check the inequality
$$\left( \binom{n}{k} - \binom{n-k}{k} \right) / \binom{n}{k} < \frac{k^2}{n}$$
which occurs in a paper I am currently reading. For fixed $k$ and $n\to \infty$ one should get asymptotic equality. There should be a "elementary" proof. Here is my question:

**Why does this inequality hold?**

Direct calculation didn't succeed so far. It might be useful to observe that the inequality is equivalent to

$$ 1- \binom{n-k}{k}/\binom{n}{k} < \frac{k^2}{n} .$$
The asymptotic equality will probably follow directly from the proof.

Comment: To check, why the focus on the asymptotic equality? Aren't you mainly concerned with proving it for fixed integers?

Comment: @CalvinLin The paper uses the asymtotic equality, that's why I'm also interested in that. Nevertheless, the main focus of the question is on the inequality. I think that the asymptotic behaviour will be a direct conclusion from the proof.

Comment: The asymptotic inequality is pretty obvious directly, because ${ n-k \choose k } / { n \choose k } =  [ (n-k)! ( n-k)! ] / [ n! (n-2k)! ]  = \prod_{i=0}^k (n-k -i) / ( n-i) \rightarrow 1^k = 1. \quad $ (Uncertain) In fact, the desired inequality might also follow from this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set chosen uniformly at random from all size $k$ subsets of $[n]=\{1,2,\dots n\}$.   The probability that $S$ is also a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n-k\}$ is $\frac{\binom{n-k}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}$.  So the left side of your inequality corresponds to the probability that $S$ contains at least one number larger than $n-k$.  Call this event $A$.

We can think of $S$ as $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k\}$, where the $x_i$ are $k$ elements successively drawn randomly without replacement from $[n]$.  Note that each $x_i$ is uniform on $[n]$ (this is clear for $x_1$, and by symmetry $x_j$ and $x_1$ have the same distribution for $j>1$) , but the $x_i$ are not independent due to the constraints that they are all unequal.

For $1 \leq j \leq k$, let $A_j$ be the event that $x_j$ is the *first* of the $x_i$ which is larger than $n-k$.  In other words, $A_j$ is the event that all of $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{j-1}$ are at most $n-k$, but $x_{j}>n-k$.  This event is disjoint, and their union is $A$.  It follows that
$$P(A) = \sum_{j=1}^k P(A_j)$$

But $P(A_1)=\frac{k}{n}$, and for $j > 1$ we have
$$P(A_j) < P(x_j>n-k) = \frac{k}{n}$$
So this last sum is strictly less than $\frac{k^2}{n}$.

Comment: A very nice proof. Calvin Lins answer makes me hope that there is also a "pure" combinatorical proof. I will formally accept your answer as soon as this proof has reached me. By now of course +1

Comment: @exiting_math Being uniform, all this is purely combinatorial. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

(Not quite as sharp as you asked for, but good enough for your purposes.)

For $ n < 2k$,  the LHS is 1 and the RHS is $ >1$, so done.

Henceforth, assume that $ n \geq 2k$ (so we don't divide by 0).

Show that  (Fill in the gaps. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.)

1.
$$ \frac{ n \choose k } { n - k \choose k } = \frac{ (n-k)! (n-k)! } { n! (n-2k)! } = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{ n-k-i } { n-i }.$$

2.

$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{ n-k-i } { n-i } = \prod ( 1 - \frac{k}{n-i}) \geq 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{k}{n-i} \geq  1 - \frac{k^2} { n-k+1}.$$

3.

$$\left( \binom{n}{k} - \binom{n-k}{k} \right) / \binom{n}{k} \leq \frac{k^2}{n-k + 1}$$

Comment: Could you explain the first inequality $\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (1-k/(n-i) \geq 1- \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} k/(n-1)$? It seems obvious but I cant find a convincing argument. I know that $ 0 < k/(n-i) <1$.  It reminds me of $(1-q)^k$ with $0<q<1$.

Comment: Just for the notification.

Comment: @exiting_math It's a standard inequality involving products: $ \prod (1 - a_i )  = 1 - \sum a_i + \sum a_i a_j \ldots \geq  1 - \sum a_i $, where $0 < a_i < 1 $.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! A nice way to see this inequality are elementary symmetric polynomials. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)